# Making button use animation for un-hovering mouse

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am trying to make a navigation button that opens a sidenav bar.

```
.navButton {
font-size: 70;
padding: 0 16.3 0 11.25; 
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
animation-name: navButtonUnfade;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.navButton:hover {
animation-name: navButtonFade;
animation-duration: 0.5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

But whenever I load the page it obviously plays the animation. How can I avoid this?

Comment: usually, this is due to `transition`. give your html and more css pls

Comment: Put some live example of your project.